# Google maps: Reading geocode per XML

Tags: php, xml, google-maps, geocoding

I have the following code for converting a PHP variable (including an address) into coordinates:

```
$evdata_address = urlencode($evdata_address);
$mapsurl = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=' . $evdata_address . '&sensor=true';
  $xml = simplexml_load_file($mapsurl);
  $status = $xml->status;
  if ($status == 'OK') {
      $latitude = $xml->result->geometry->location->lat;
      $longitude = $xml->result->geometry->location->lng;
  };
```

For some reason it works perfectly on my own webspace/server but does not work on the remote server where the site has to be launched. Both servers are based on PHP 7.0.

I am getting OVER_QUERY_LIMIT for $xml->status

Comment: 1. a key is now required. 2. the sensor parameter is no longer needed.

Comment: where is a key reuqired? in $mapsurl ? i tried it.. then i get "request denied" or something for $xml->status ... Or how has the key to be implemented? like
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=' . $evdata_address . '&key=[key]
should it be the same key that i am using for my maps javascript?

Thank you!

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start#get-a-key

Comment: @muzzie, try to replace `http` with `https`. This may resolve the "request denied" problem.

Comment: @lonut, i apoint you the most helpful person on stackoverflow. it works! and again: thank you :)

Comment: @muzzie, awesome. :) I'm glad it worked. Happy to help.